# watch doesn't display steps from Google Fit

Tags: google-fit

How do I set up my watch app to show steps on Google Fit, instead of move minutes? Or is this just the newest version? It's actually not even showing those at this point, just a constant update symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Google Fit recommends reading by data type to get the values as the Google Fit app. This includes reading the current daily step count by calling HistoryClient.readDailyTotal, see official docs for sample application  [developers.google.com/fit/scenarios/read-daily-step-total](https://developers.google.com/fit/scenarios/read-daily-step-total)